# Webpack module rule to serve icons from CDN

Tags: webpack, cdn, jsdelivr

My app provides a dropdown of icons. We're using [simple-icons](https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons), [bootstrap-icons](https://github.com/twbs/icons), and some custom icons that we developed in-house.

Those icons are hosted by our application using a [webpack module rule](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulerules). For example, this is what the rule looks like for simple-icons:

```
{
  test: /simple-icons\/.*\.svg$/,
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    filename: "icons/simple-icons/[name][ext]",
  },
},
```

This tells webpack to copy all SVG files from the simple-icons npm package to the `icons/simple-icons/` folder in the final build. These icons are then accessible on our website at their respective paths. For example, the `github.svg` file is accessible at `<BASE_URL>/icons/simple-icons/github.svg`.

This approach works fine but it bloats the bundle size. Would be great to serve these icons from a CDN and remove them from the bundle.

I thought about writing the icons to S3 but realized they are already hosted by CDN's, e.g. jsDelivr. So I changed the rule above so my app will serve the icons from jsDelivr:

```
{
  test: /simple-icons\/.*\.svg$/,
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    emit: false,
    publicPath: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@${
      require("simple-icons/package.json").version
    }/`,
    filename: "icons/[name][ext]",
  },
},
```

Note, `emit=False` tells webpack NOT to copy the file to the server, which makes sense because the files are already there.

This removes the icons from the bundle and allows me to pull them from jsDelivr. Are there any major cons with this approach / implementation? I'm very new to webpack so just wondering if I configured this correctly.

Comment: I'm reading about [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/). Wondering if that would be a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the rule to the following:

```json
{
  test: /.*node_modules[\/\\]simple-icons.*\.svg$/,
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    emit: false,
    publicPath: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@9.16.0/`,
    filename: "icons/[name][ext]",
  },
},
```

The `[\/\\]` ensures Windows paths are valid.
`node_modules` ensures that it won't accidentally pick up project files (developer putting an svg into a simple-icons folder).

Apart from that it seems perfectly fine.

Regarding webpack external:
This would not magically solve your problems.
Externals only remove the dependency from the output; you will still have to provide it somehow.
This would mean significantly more work for you (configuring webpack), when your idea already makes everything with little additional configuration.